# Calculate length of string using yahoo pipes

Tags: string, replace, substring, yahoo-pipes

I am using yahoo pipes to fetch articles from various sources including google, however articles from google include the title and source of title in the description, is there a way in yahoo pipes to remove the title & source and leave the rest of article intact.  I tried to use sub-string however it requires length of the string which is variable for each article.  I guess if there is way to calculate the length of title and source and pass it to sub-string module this may work.

Any help would be great.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=8KZMRx473hGtVMYsP27D0g, which can be used as a subpipe (i.e. within a loop) to calculate the length of a string. It should be relatively straightforward to add a second text input module and modify the Pipe to cater for your second text string.